# Having an issue reading in a CSV File for a project

Tags: java, csv

Hi I'm getting a NumberFormatException error for reading in this CSV text file for a project. Here's the CSV

```
12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,PGH,2
24680,Smoke Shifter,0.98,PGH,48
86420,Pre-dug Post Hole,2.49,ATL,34
25632,Acme Widget,98.29,LOU,342
97531,Anti-Gravity Turbine,895.29,ATL,3
24680,Battery-Powered Battery Charger,252.98,ATL,2
12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,LOU,35
97531,Anti-Gravity Turbine,895.29,PHL,8
00000,Glass Hammer,105.90,PGH,8
01020,Inflatable Dartboard,32.95,PGH,453
86420,Pre-dug Post Hole,2.49,LOU,68
86420,Pre-dug Post Hole,2.49,PGH,124
24680,Battery-Powered Battery Charger,252.98,PHL,5
```

I have a general understanding what is going on. The error is appearing I believe because it reaches the end of the first line and then the error pops up

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: "2 24680"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Prog7
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String warehouseID = null;
        String city = null;
        String state = null;
        int partNumber = 0;
        String description = null;
        double price = 0.0;
        int quantity = 0;
        int count = 0;

        int numWarehouse = 4;
        int numParts = 13;
        Scanner warehouseFile = null;
        Scanner partFile = null;

        Warehouse[] warehouse = new Warehouse[10];
        Part[] parts = new Part[20];

        try
        {
            warehouseFile = new Scanner(new File("warehouse.txt"));
            while (warehouseFile.hasNext())
            {
                warehouseID = warehouseFile.next();
                city = warehouseFile.next();
                state = warehouseFile.next();
                warehouse[count] = new Warehouse(warehouseID, city, state);
                count++;
            }

            partFile = new Scanner(new File("parts.txt"));
            partFile.useDelimiter(",");
            while (partFile.hasNext())
            {
                partNumber = Integer.parseInt(partFile.next());
                description = partFile.next();
                price = Double.parseDouble(partFile.next());
                warehouseID = partFile.next();
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(partFile.next());
                parts[count] = new Part(partNumber, description, price, warehouseID, quantity);
                count++;

            }

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.print("warehouse.txt or parts.txt not found");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numWarehouse; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5s %5s %5s\n", warehouse[i].getWarehouseID(), warehouse[i].getCity(),
                    warehouse[i].getState());

            for (int j = 0; j < numParts; j++)
            {
                if (parts[j].getWarehouseID().equals(warehouse[i].getWarehouseID()))
                {
                    System.out.printf("%5s %5s %10.2f %5\nd", parts[j].getPartNumber(), parts[j].getDescription(),
                            parts[j].getPrice(), parts[j].getQuantity());

                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

I think it has something to do with the program is reading in each value but then there's nothing for going to the next line. I have a tried a partFile.nextLine() instruction and a hasNextLine() while loop and I still get the same error. Is there something perhaps I could do with a newline character?

Comment: Hint: Newline is no delimiter, only comma is. The method useDelimiter takes a regular expression, where you can specify "comma or newline" as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
        partFile.useDelimiter(",");
```

You are telling the scanner to split only on commas.  Once it reaches the last item in the first line of `parts.txt`, it reads onwards until it finds the first comma in the next line, and hence returns `2` followed by an end-of-line followed by `24680` as the next item.

You don't just want to split by commas, you also want to split by newline characters as well.  [`useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) takes a regular expression: the following tells the scanner to split on either a comma or any combination of newline characters:

```
        partFile.useDelimiter(",|[\\r\\n]+");
```

Comment: Okay that helps a lot actually I will give a try. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Luke Woodward's answer, perhaps you should take into account that the year is 2018, not 1999. The following code should do what you're looking for, with the knowledge of how to parse a line moved into the class where it belongs. I made it a constructor, but it could also be a static `valueOf` method.

```
Path warehouseFile = Paths.get("warehouse.txt");
Files.lines(warehouseFile)
  .map(Warehouse::new)
  .collect(toList());

static class Warehouse {
  public Warehouse(String line) {...}
}
```